# Calling Functor in pair in array (C++)

Tags: c++, functor

I have defined an array as:

```
std::array<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<OpCode>, std::shared_ptr<Argument>>, 256> opcodes;
```

where `Opcode` and `Argument` are base classes for functors for interpreting data in Metafont GF files. A typical implementation looks like:

```
class skip: public OpCode {
public:
    using OpCode::OpCode;
    void operator()(std::int_fast32_t argument) override {
        character_context->next_line(argument);
        character_context->make_white();
    }
};
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
opcodes[opcode].first(opcodes[opcode].second(opcode));
```

to interpret each opcode in the GF file. (As an aside, typing that code above makes me think that I'm likely to want to use a custom class in place of `pair` so that I don't have to have duplicated references to `opcodes[opcode]` but that’s for a further revision.)

What I've noticed in CLion is that it insists that to be able to call my `operator()`, it expects me to write something like this instead:

```
int_fast32_t arg = opcodes[opcode].second->operator()(opcode);
```

So two questions:

1. Is there a different/better way to manage my data structure so I don't have to explicitly call `operator()` like the above?
2. Is there a more idiomatic structure I should be using to manage my Functors (assuming that they're even the right tool for the job) to enable stepping through the GF byte code?

Comment: Try using `(opcodes[opcode].first)(opcodes[opcode].second(opcode));`?

Comment: @NathanOliver first and second are pointers, some `*` missing I think

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Aha.  Right you are.  Most likely `(*opcodes[opcode].first)(opcodes[opcode].second(opcode));` would work.

Comment: now I am not sure what the question is actually about. Is it only the `x->operator()( ...)` vs `(*x)( ... )` thing that disturbs you? Note that asking for different/better ways is borderline opinion based.

Comment: @NathanOliver `second` is a pointer too ;)

Comment: It appears the thing throwing me off is the use of the `std::shared_ptr` in the array. I'm thinking that Java habits may be messing me up here and I may not want to actually use pointers there,

Comment: I wouldnt pick the data structure based on clumsy looking syntax. If you dont like to write it more than once you can use a function that lets you write `int_fast32_t arg = get_arg(opcode);`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 What the clumsy-looking syntax tells me is that there's probably a better way to do things than the approach I've taken. One of my guiding principals is that if a tool is making things awkward then either I'm using the tool wrong or it's the wrong tool for the job. The same thing applies at a lower level with language features and syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there a different/better way to manage my data structure so I don't have to explicitly call operator() like the above?

Well, if you don't store pointers, you don't need to dereference them. For example, if your functors are flyweights, you don't need to store owning pointers everywhere, and can just use

```
array<pair<std::reference_wrapper<OpCode>, std::reference_wrapper<Argument>>, 256> opcodes;
```

> 2. Is there a more idiomatic structure I should be using to manage my Functors

if you're always chaining them anyway, you can do that explicitly:

```
array<std::function<void(int_fast32_t)>, 256> opcodes;

void bind_opcode(int_fast32_t op, OpCode* foo, Argument* bar)
{
  opcodes[op] = [=](int_fast32_t x) { (*foo)((*bar)(x)); }
}
```

(obviously that can use raw pointers, shared pointers, references if you're certain the object lifetimes are guaranteed elsewhere ... or if the `OpCode` and `Argument` objects are not that big, you could template the function and just copy the concrete functors by value).
}

Comment: The more I look at it, the more I learn from your answer. I wish I could upvote it more than once. Particularly the idea about making the array one of `std::function` which I can actually use to refactor things. Most of the `Argument` functors don't actually use their argument and those that do generally only use it to return the bare opcode (opcodes 0–63, for example are equivalent to `paint(opcode)` and I can just create a lambda with the opcode (or opcode minus a constant) rather than use a functor. My code is measurably better because of your answer.

Comment: I'm really glad it helped!